# Find files containing two separate words in text

Tags: unix, grep

My UNIX is quite rusty but what I want is to search a location in UNIX for files containing the two separate words in their text of "generate" and "process", but both words on the SAME LINE?

I know there are script files that contain details of the script author and its function noted at the top of the script. For example, the start of one such script contains the following;

function:   generate sales overtime process

I have tried things like the following (again my UNIX is rusty)

```
grep -rwl . -e "generate" | "process"
```

But this gives errors such unrecognised commands

What I want is a list of Progress files like;

salesovertime1.p

salestravel1.p

salesexpenses1.p

salesexpenses2.p

Comment: What version of `grep` do you happen to have? Can you output `grep --version` and paste it here?

Comment: Also can you post your requirement with a proper example, like your input and the exact output you want to get?

Comment: @Inian I have added as much information as I could.  Not sure how to find the version of Grep but I think we are running Solaris 10

Comment: Can you see if the `grep` you have is `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`

Comment: do you want files containing either term (easy to do with `grep -e 'generate' -e 'process'`) or both those terms in single line (and do you want to match those terms in any order)?

Comment: @Sundeep yes I want both files that have both these strings in a single line.  Thanks

Comment: @jack95 can you also add the possibilities? `function: generate sales overtime process` is one sample... do you also want to match lines that has `process` first and `generate` later? for ex: `this process has a generate term`

Answer (score 0):

If you search for file then `find` is appropriate, and then you may filter with `grep`:

```
find .  -exec grep -H generate {} \; 2> /dev/null | grep process
```

will find recursively every file form the current directory, then filter ones that contains word "generate" and the filter again with ones that contains word "process". Filenames will be produced on output with option `-H` (GNU grep) and error messages begin redirected to `/dev/null`.

Now if you want filenames only, you can use :

```
find .  -exec grep -H generate {} \; 2> /dev/null | grep process | cut -f1 -d\:
```

If you want "generate" and "process" in the same file but on different lines, the following will do it:

```
grep process `find .  -exec grep -H generate {} \; 2> /dev/null | cut -f1 -d\:` 2> /dev/null | cut -f1 -d\:
```

The `find` generates a file list that is used to `grep` against and extract filenames with redirecting errors again.

Comment: Rather than redirecting errors, you probably want `find . -type f -exec ...`.  You will still get error messages for permission issues, but the error for directories will be removed.

Comment: The a mix of both... Thanks

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks for this Jean - I should have said in my original question I am looking for the files that have both words on the same line!!!

Comment: Then the first solution ;-)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks again jean.  Yes I tried that one and it run very quickly but where does it output to.  I need to see the list of files!